# How to add XSAPI to C# UWP project in VS 2017

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2017, xbox-live

I am trying to follow "How to link against the XSAPI WinRT UWP source" instructions from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/xbox-live-api/blob/master/LINKTOSOURCE.md) to add Xbox Service API to my C# Universal Windows 10 project (Visual Studio 2017).

Instructions say to use version 141 for VS 2017, but Microsoft.Xbox.Services.141.UWP.WinRT project does not exist and "140" is failing with "The application which this project type is based on was not found."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For WinRT, we only build a single WinRT DLL that supports VS2015 and VS2017.  To use it from source, you'll need to install 140 support in VS2017.  Run the VS2017 installer, modify, and go to Individual components tab and choose "VS++ 2015.3 v140 toolset".  Then you should be able to open \Build\Microsoft.Xbox.Services.140.UWP.WinRT\Microsoft.Xbox.Services.140.UWP.WinRT.vcxproj by itself in VS2017 and build it. Then you can follow the steps in that doc to link to source.

I'll update this doc link with this info.

You can ask Xbox Live related non-programming questions here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=xboxlivedev